# Double Buffering in F#: what is the deal with the flicker?

Tags: winforms, f#

I am trying to implement double buffering in F#.  All of the examples I am running into are C#.

```
    let r = form.DisplayRectangle
    let buffer = new Bitmap(r.Width,r.Height)
    form.DrawToBitmap(buffer,r)
    form.BackgroundImage <-buffer
    form.Invalidate()
```

Although the problem is an "easy" fix, the private variables are not exposed in F#.  Instead, I have to initialize the form in C#.  There must be a way though (it seems like this is a trivial thing) to expose the private variables for the form in F#.

Comment: You seem to have been submitting many edits which significantly change the meaning of your questions. Please note this is not fair to those who have already answered the question; as someone may come by and down vote their answers since it will *appear* that they have not answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

Do

```
form.DoubleBuffered <- true
```

then no flicker

Comment: Problem: Double buffer isn't showing up, and the compiler says it is a private variable...

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Form` [definitely does have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) a `DoubleBuffered` property...

Comment: Normally easiest to create a thin wrapper over `Form` and overwrite it in the constructor

Comment: @JoelMueller - the propertyy is protected so you can only access it from inherited classes - see my other comment for the simplest solution

Comment: So it is. I guess I never noticed because in C# WinForms work it's typical for each form you create to inherit from `Form`.